# Weird Styling Issue in IE involving <td>

Tags: css, internet-explorer, styles, compatibility

I'm fairly new to CSS, but I'm having a weird styling issue only occurring in IE. Upon clicking anywhere in a , a odd border appears around each  within the row (see screenshot). Has anyone else ever encountered this behaviour? I can attach some code if necessary.

Thanks

[image: Bovine is normal behaviour, Buffalo is the anomaly]

Comment: I am pretty sure it is highlighting the column

Answer (score 0):

css

disappear border on click

```
outline: none;
```

disappear shadow  inside box

```
box-shadow: none;
```

add border

```
border: 1px solid gray;
```